# what does this command do internally? openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key?

Tags: perl, openssl, rsa

If I run the command:
`openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key`

Then I get this output:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICdQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAl8wggJbAgEAAoGBAJymFcYButtSdq6a
. . .
ROHl3KioElE/sRvPEHxJp5Bqlr2UmWSs4oMcDBVLfY609YKZTeKw6NuqH4xzd81F
7Rj3Gr6eyKeC
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I need to generate this same output on my PERL script so I can pass it to:

```
Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($key_string);
```

and sign my data.

So I'm asking:
what does this command do internally?

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key
```

So I can translate the process into perl.

This is what I have so far:

I load the ASN.1 syntax of pkcs8 and now I can get the blocks of data by reference:

```
$pkcs8 = Convert::ASN1->new(encoding => 'DER');
$pkcs8->prepare(q<
--PrivateKey 
            EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
                encryptionAlgorithm  EncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier,
                encryptedData        EncryptedData 
                }

            EncryptionAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

            EncryptedData ::= OCTET STRING

            AlgorithmIdentifier ::= SEQUENCE {
                algorithm OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
                parameters ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL }
            >);
```

The resulf of loading the .key file and make a dump is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'encryptionAlgorithm' => {
binary data                 'parameters' => binary data¸
                                     'algorithm' => '1.2.840.113549.1.5.13'
                                   },
          'encryptedData' => ' . . . .  binary data . . . .  . '
        };
```

What I believe is that **encryptedData** is encoded using pkcs5 according to the OID **1.2.840.113549.1.5.13**

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in file.key` command is just converting the input from DER to PEM and printing it out.  The PEM encoding is just a base64 encoding of the binary DER, with the BEGIN and END lines added.

```
use File::Slurp;
use MIME::Base64;

$der = read_file('file.key');

$pem = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
     . encode_base64($der)
     . "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

print $pem;
```

This should give you basically the same output as the openssl command (except that MIME::Base64 uses 76-character output lines by default, whereas standard PEM encoding uses 64-character lines.... but I doubt that will matter for your purposes)